# Change event called when changing element value IE 11/Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I've created an directive to work with files. When I change the file or select a new one I call this code:

`element.val('');`

I'm doing this to be able to remove the selected file and select the same after that. If I don't do this, when I delete the selected file and select the same again, then the `change` event won't be called and I can't do what I need to do.

I just need to know if there is a way of avoid IE to call the change event when I change the value of the input.

I searched a little bit and found comments like this:

`The onchange event on textboxes and textarea elements only fires when the element loses focus, and if its value is now other than its value when it got focus.`

So, this change event was not supposed to be called when I just change de value programatically.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I've created a jsfiddle with the [behaviour](https://jsfiddle.net/ZG9re/7063/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that `element.val('')` emit a new `change` event, causing multiple calls to your listener. That said, you can avoid this weird behavior by checking the input value like the following:

```
element.bind('change', function(){
    if(!element.val()) {
      return;
    }
    element.val('');
    // code goes here
});
```

Comment: element.bind is deprecated, instead this use on().